# Javascript object computed property

Tags: javascript

Could you please explain me what happens in code bellow? Why both of the expressions have same value?

```js
let a = {};

let b = {
    value: 'b'
};

let c = {
    value: 'c'
};

a[b]=123;
a[c]=456;

console.log(a[b], a[c]); // ==> 456 456
```

Any link to study material are welcome

Comment: `console.log(a)`. See what `b` and `c` used as an object property compute to.

Answer (score 3):

Object keys may only be strings. When you put an *object* in a computed property, it will be stringified to `[object Object]`, so `a[b]` is the same as `a[c]`: `a['[object Object]']`.

```js
let a = {};

let b = {
    value: 'b'
};

let c = {
    value: 'c'
};

a[b]=123;
a[c]=456;

console.log(a);
```

So, the final assignment of 456 to the `[object Object]` key overwrites the prior assignment of 123 (and the resulting object only has that one key).

If you want to safely use objects as "keys", use a Map instead, whose keys can be of *any type*, not just strings:

```js
const a = new Map();

let b = {
    value: 'b'
};

let c = {
    value: 'c'
};

a.set(b, 123);
a.set(c, 456);
console.log(a.get(b));
console.log(a.get(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy:

When you do

```
a[b]=123;
a[c]=456;
```

you set an object as a propery name of `a`.

The thing is, a property name is a string, so, `toString()` is called on `b` and `c` (which are objects), and that makes the same value. Do you get it?

```js
let a = {};

let b = {
    value: 'b'
};

let c = {
    value: 'c'
};

a[b]=123;
a[c]=456;

console.log(a[b], a[c]); // ==> 456 456
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `a[b] = //...` expression, `b` gets coerced to string - and the result of that conversion is a string `"[object Object]"`. And it's the same value for `c`.

```js
let a = {};

let b = {
    value: 'b'
};

let c = {
    value: 'c'
};

a[b]=123;
a[c]=456;

console.log(b.toString());
console.log(c.toString());

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Object's key can be string and you are trying to assign a object as the key, js typecasts the object to string and the key becomes [object Object] for both the objects. That is why the value is updated against the same key.